# Android: why am i unable to use a selector for TextView background

Tags: android, selector

My selector is:

```
<item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="@color/bg_grey"/>
<item android:state_focused="true" android:color="@color/bg_grey"/>
<item android:color="@color/white"/>
```

and i have my TextView as:

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/textview_selector"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="Some Text"
        android:textColor="@color/text_grey"
        android:textSize="16dp" />
```

This way i am getting:

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary xml file line #68: Error inflating class <unknown>
```

if i am using this selector as `android:textColor="@drawable/textview_selector"` its working fine

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem here is that you cannot define the background color using a color selector, you need a drawable selector. So, the necessary changes would look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/selected_state" />
</selector>
```

You would also need to move that resource to the drawable directory where it would make more sense since it's not a color selector per se.

Then you would have to create the res/drawable/selected_state.xml file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="@color/bg_grey" />
</shape>
```

and finally, you would use it like this:

```
android:background="@drawable/selector"
```

Answer (score 1):

You are defining Color in place of a background Drawable in Selectors xml,try with backgrounds
drawable

Answer (score 0):

you just need to ensure the colors are in colors.xml file and do not put the hex colors directly into the selector items.

my_selector.xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item android:drawable="@color/category_item_selected_color" android:state_selected="true"/>
        <item android:drawable="@color/category_item_selected_color" android:state_pressed="true"/>
        <item android:drawable="@color/white" />
    </selector>
```

and make your textview look like this:

```
 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_name"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:letterSpacing="0.05"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textSize="17sp"
    tools:text="New In"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:background="@drawable/my_selector"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    />
```